# Simple login form with SenchaTouch

Tags: forms, authentication, sencha-touch

Just diving into SenchaTouch which seems very promising.

I'm building my first application, a simple login form check source http://pastebin.com/8Zddr9cj

I'm looking for a way to do the following things :

- Display 'nice' error message when the login/password is wrong. Can be in red to replace the 'Please enter your credentials); i don't know how to access this property.
- If login success, close the form and load the application (probably another js file).

Quite simple, but i'm a newbie to this,

Answer (score 1):

1) Fieldset has a method called `setInstructions` which you can call to update the instructions. So, you could specify an `id` configuration in your field set, then use that later on when you want to update the instructions.

```
...
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        id: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Login',
        instructions: 'Please enter your credentials',
        defaults: {
            required: true,
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelWidth: '40%'
        },
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name : 'email',
            label: 'Email',
            placeHolder: 'your@email.com',
            useClearIcon: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name : 'password',
            label: 'Password',
            useClearIcon: false
        }]
    }
],
...

//wherever you want to update the instructions
var fieldset = Ext.getCmp('fieldset');
fieldset.setInstructions('My new instructions!');
```

2) Here is a simple demo of this:

```
//create a panel, which is full screen, and will contain your form, and another item
//which you want to show at some point
var wrapper = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',

    //my two items
    items: [
        form,
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'my second panel, which is not visible on render.'
        }
    ]
});

//change the active card/item, when you need to
wrapper.setActiveItem(1); //starts at 0
```

Make sure you remove fullscreen from your form, as it is no longer fullscreen (this wrapper panel is).