# How to validate a login page using sencha

Tags: validation, authentication, extjs

HI Ive created a login page using sencha. But i am not sure as to how i can use a validation to use along with sencha. I would like to do a javascript validation. If so how i should do it in such a way that submit can be used to call a function. Also if there is proper validation with sencha itself please let me know.

Many thanks

Roy M J

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339831/simple-login-form-with-senchatouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add validation while you are creating a store as shown

```
Ext.regModel('Note', {
            idProperty: 'id',
            fields: [
                { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' },
                { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'narrative', type: 'string' }
            ],
            validations: [
                { type: 'presence', field: 'id' },
                { type: 'presence', field: 'title', message: 'Please enter a title for this note.' }
            ]
        });
```

and use this on submission

```
var errors = currentNote.validate();
                        if (!errors.isValid()) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField('title')[0].message, Ext.emptyFn);
                            return;
                        }
```

You can use this tuitorial by **Jorge** for more clarity

http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/

Hope it will help...